# Stereo Bundle Adjustment

Tags: slam, computer-vision, stereo-vision, visual-odometry

When doing stereo based visual odometry and bundle adjustment how does the stereo constraint get factored into the photometric error?

Do you use the fact the second cameras location is known wrt the first or is something else done?

Comment: Do you care for the photometric error version or the reprojection error one? I just ask because almost all bundle adjustment algorithms optimize the reprojection error. Photometric optimization is possible, but happens quite rarely and is more used in the occasional direct visual odometry algorithm. Though the vast majority again use the reprojection error.

Comment: It should be reproduction error though photometric is like dense reprojection tight?

Comment: semi-dense, epipolar, reprojection, ect. all can be used as a stereo constraint.